# Odd screenshot naming difference between linux and windows

Tags: atata

Here are snippets from  two different test logs.

Linux does this on a screenshot:

2022-01-07 19:34:02.6043  INFO - Screenshot saved to file "/source/fs.automation.fsol/FS.Automation.Tests/bin/Debug/net5.0/Logs/2022-01-07 19_33_47/CharityAKA/01 - "Charity Details FSOL" page - Test Failure.png"

Windows does this:

2021-12-17 22:49:29.5490 INFO - Screenshot saved to file "C:\BuildAgent\work\84629dc95880ab61\fs.automation.impactfully\FS.Automation.Tests\bin\Debug\net5.0\Logs\2021-12-17 22_48_13\ImportedCharityList\01 - Search Charities Impactfully Tab page - Test Failure.png"

Notice the double quotes in the file name in linux that are not there when running in windows - is thing something  that can be made uniform between linux and windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atata sanitizes the file names to be valid for current OS. Double quotes is invalid file name character in Windows, so they are removed there. But I agree that a name should be the same for both OS.

The default screenshot file name format renders `PageObjectFullName` property, which looks like `"Charity Details FSOL" page`. But we can configure format to use `{PageObjectName} {PageObjectTypeName}` instead, which will render `Charity Details FSOL page` without quotes. You can reconfigure a screenshot file name format this way:

```
AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration
    .AddScreenshotFileSaving()
        .WithFileName(screenshotInfo => $"{screenshotInfo.Number:D2} - {screenshotInfo.PageObjectName} {screenshotInfo.PageObjectTypeName}{screenshotInfo.Title?.Prepend(" - ")}");
```

Or:

```
AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration
    .AddScreenshotFileSaving()
        .WithFileName("{screenshot-number:D2} - {screenshot-pageobjectname} {screenshot-pageobjecttypename}{screenshot-title: - *}")
```

By the way, I will apply such format as the default for Atata v2. Thanks for finding and reporting this issue.